# Custom errors messages with Bison

Tags: c, parsing, grammar, bison

With Bison, I generate custom error messages with the function: `int yyreport_syntax_error (const yypcontext_t *ctx)` by specifying `%define parse.error custom`.

I am looking for a feature to display also the expected **nonterminals** (that are listed after the tokens in `yysymbol_kind_t`).  Is there some Bison feature to do this?

```
static int yyreport_syntax_error (const yypcontext_t *ctx)
{
  int res = 0;
  YYLOCATION_PRINT (stderr, *yypcontext_location (ctx));
  fprintf (stderr, ": syntax error");
  // Report the tokens expected at this point.
  {
    enum { TOKENMAX = 5 };
    yysymbol_kind_t expected[TOKENMAX];
    int n = yypcontext_expected_tokens (ctx, expected, TOKENMAX);
    if (n < 0)
      // Forward errors to yyparse.
      res = n;
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        fprintf (stderr, "%s %s",
                 i == 0 ? ": expected" : " or", yysymbol_name (expected[i]));
  }
  // Report the unexpected token.
  {
    yysymbol_kind_t lookahead = yypcontext_token (ctx);
    if (lookahead != YYSYMBOL_YYEMPTY)
      fprintf (stderr, " before %s", yysymbol_name (lookahead));
  }
  fprintf (stderr, "\n");
  return res;
}
```

Bison version 3.8.2

Comment: You actually can't do this accurately, because of LALR(1) parse table state compression. There have been numerous articles published over the last five decades as to how to do it approximately.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a reference for the articles you mention?

Comment: kello: See [Dick Grune's massive annotated bibliography](https://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_2nd_Edition/CompleteList.pdf) (from the web-page associated with his highly-recommended text *Parsing Techniques: A Practical Guide*). Section 18.2.7 (Error Handling) has a list of about 150 annotated references covering the period from 1967 to 2005. (The 2nd edition of the text was published in 2008, and Grune is now retired. So it's not quite the 50 years @user207421 refers to, but it's a very good start.)

Comment: @rici What a bibliography! Mostly about recovery rather than messages of course. I think I have a book in the garage that shows how to do it with *yacc(1),* will check.

Comment: @rici It is impressive though I found a mistake in it. He writes about 'damp squib' and a book called 'damp squid', saying that the latter is a corruption of squib which is a firecracker. That's true but damp squib is actually a Britishism and so the words are together not as one each. It's just that damp squib is sometimes misheard as damp squid. Might call it an eggcorn.  OT of course but that's something of interest to some maybe.